# Valuably vs in a valuable manner

Tags: grammar

I came across a word that I am not sure if I ever came across before: **valuably**

I believe the context was: "She contributed valuably to the discusion..."
I would normally have said this as "She contributed to the discussion in a valuable manner..."

The second sounds more correct- but is the first sentence also grammatically correct?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Valuably* is a valid, if seldom-used, form of the word [*valuable*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/valuably?s=t).  So the first sentence is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Though grammatically correct, it would be much more natural to say, "She made a valuable contribution to the discussion."